# What Should I Develop First When Using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am completely new to AngularJS and really like the look of it, from what I can gather Angular JS seems to be a MVC that is run on the front end instead of using a backend language to manage that?

So I'm trying to create a very simple list app that will display list items on the front end and then a backend to post the items to the database.

With Angular JS I really don't know where to start as I couldn't imagine writing PHP for the database calls first.

When developing an Angular JS app do you first start with the front end and MVC components of Angular then add the data calls later?

I don't mean this to be opinionated however I'm just wondering if you build the front end components and then wire the data methods in after?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: This is indeed an opinion question. You can write them in whichever order you prefer.

Comment: Welcome to angular world! Check egghead.io site, this is perfect place where you can read more about angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is indeed arbitrary. Recently I have finished my first AngularJS application so I understand your dillema... you can follow my way:

1. Prepare a file like `app.js` and initialize whole app (using `angular.module`).
2. Prepare `index.html`, include needed scripts/styles and `<ng-view>` (or alternatively `<ui-view>`, see step 3 for difference) as a placeholder for all views.
3. Think what views you will need and what transitions between them will work well. Then prepare `xxx.html` template for each view and describe transitions between views using `ducatsApp.config` (you can use `routeProvider` or `stateProvider`, in latter case the view placeholder in index.html shall be referred to as `<ui-view>`). Prepare also special route for errorneous links using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`.
4. Test your routing.
5. Prepare file like `controllers.js` with all controllers - each non-static view created in step 3 shall have a controller.
6. Inside controllers communicate with views using `$scope` and communicate with backend using `$http`, e.g.:

   ```
   this.getUsers = function() {

       return $http({
           method: 'GET', 
           url: "/users",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
       });
   };
   ```
7. For learning purposes you can simulate backend using `$httpBackend`. This is very nice feature of Angular framework. Remember that `$httpBackend` captures all http request attempts, so you have at least to make an exception for your html views, e.g. like that: `$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/views\//).passThrough();`.
   Then you can put http requests handling in `backend.js` like that:

   ```
   $httpBackend.whenGET('/users').respond(function(method, url, data) {
       return [200, getUsers()]; 
   });
   ```

and implement respective functions (like `getUsers()` above) which will simulate server behaviour. So you do not need to implement any real backend and you can practive your JavaScript.

7. Inside `backend.js` you can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` HTML5 feature which is perfect if you want to simulate really small data storage.
8. You can also identify some functionalities which may be commonly used by several controllers. Such functionalities you can put separately in `services.js` file. But this is not mandatory for having up-and-running application.

If you follow these guidelines, you have E2E-like web application implemented purely on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Design a UI form.
2. Then get values from UI to controller using the binding capabilities provided by angular.
3. Post the values from controller using HTTP.
4. Spring MVC or Rest can be used for rest of the Operations starting from     getting values from angular side and up to database insertions phase.